# Add element to div in a relative position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.
In the click event, I need to add an element that will be in a `position: absolute` to his parent **where the user clicked** (not the body since the parent is `overflow: scroll;`)

The issue is to add the mark element in the correct place.

1. How can I find the top and left position of what the user highlighted?
2. How can I add the marking relative to the article element? Whenever the user scrolls, I need the mark element to stay over the highlighted text.

I'm trying to set them with the below code;

```
mark.setAttribute("style", `top:${top}px`);
mark.setAttribute("style", `left:${left}px`);
```

https://codepen.io/nemo369/pen/ExjQgKy

```js
const article =document.querySelector(`article`);

article.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  var result =  window.getSelection().toString();
  const oldMark =document.querySelector(`.mark`);
  if(oldMark){
    article.removeChild(oldMark);
  }
  window.getSelection().empty()
  if(result){
    let mark = document.createElement('mark');
    mark.innerText =  `${result}`;
    mark.classList.add('mark');
    var top = 5;
    var left = 15
mark.setAttribute("style", `top:${top}px`);
mark.setAttribute("style", `left:${left}px`);
    article.appendChild(mark);
  }
});
```

```css
main{
     display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
article{
  max-height:30%;
overflow:scroll;
  flex:0 0 50vw;
  position: relative;
}
.mark{
      position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    
    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br>
The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
          
    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br>
The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
          
    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br>
The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
  </article>
  
</main>
```

;

Comment: You might need to remove `position: relative` from the article or use `position: fixed` on the mark.

Comment: @nemo See my modified answer, need combination of offsetTop and scrollTop

Comment: Edited the question to be more precise. It already has an answer hence no need to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, I had to go back to javascript basics. Fortunately, I found the key-- there are `offsetTop, offsetLeft` properties!

So in this script, on mousedown, we're getting the event click location then subtract the offset position of the article element.

The offset position refers to how far the target element is from the start of the document.

EDIT: To handle the vertical scroll position inside the article, I added `article.scrollTop` on computation.

Run the demo below.

```js
const article = document.querySelector(`article`);

var x;
var y;

article.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  x = event.clientX;
  y = event.clientY;

  y = y - article.offsetTop + article.scrollTop - 5.5;
  x = x - article.offsetLeft + 1;
})

article.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  var result = window.getSelection().toString();
  const oldMark = document.querySelector(`.mark`);
  const body = document.querySelector(`body`);

  if (oldMark) {
    article.removeChild(oldMark);
  }
  window.getSelection().empty()
  if (result) {
    let mark = document.createElement('mark');
    mark.innerText = `${result}`;
    mark.classList.add('mark');
    mark.setAttribute("style", `top:${y}px; left:${x}px;`);
    article.appendChild(mark);
  }
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

article {
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 0 0 50vw;
  position: relative;
}

.mark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>

    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br> The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
          
    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br>
The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
          
    <p>I'm trying to build something like the highlight feature in Medium.<br>
The issue is that in the click event I need to add an element that will be in a <strong>position absolute</strong> to his parent and not the body since the parent is <strong>overflow: scroll;<strong><br>

How can I find those x and y conditions?

 </p>
  </article>
  
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this code here you can get location on your click and i guess then you can assign this x and y value to you top and left variable

```js
function printMousePos(event) {
  document.body.textContent =
    "clientX: " + event.clientX +
    " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it only the location relative to the **body** and not to the element. so with the inside scroll, the element won't be in place